# Does anyone know how to get parameter from url in .twig formate

Tags: php, opencart-3, twig-extension

Does anyone know how to get parameter from url like this:

`mywebsite.com/index.php?route=account/register&a=1&b=2`

i want to get param: `a`, `b` in .twig files opencart 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Why you need it get in twig?  You can get it in corresponding controller file:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['a'])) {
            $a = $this->request->get['a'];
} else {
$a = '';
}
if (isset($this->request->get['b'])) {
            $b = $this->request->get['b'];
} else {
$b = '';
}
```

and call in twig...

```
{{ a }} {{ b }}
```

Comment: how to send value from url param like this:
examplete > ndex.php?route=account/register&test=123
tell me how i get this "test" param in register controller

Comment: `if (isset($this->request->get['test'])) {
            $test = $this->request->get['test'];
} else {
$test = '';
}`